# iMobileDevice library how to use the Installation Proxy feature to install .mobileconfig file

Tags: c#, ios, libimobiledevice

I need to install a .mobileconfig file into iPhone as a profile, similar to how AppleConfigurator does it but I don't own a MAC. I don't know where it default installs to, should there be options included? The goal is to skip the Setup Assistant that takes place with each newly erased phone.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> udids;
int count = 0;

var idevice = LibiMobileDevice.Instance.iDevice;
var lockdown = LibiMobileDevice.Instance.Lockdown;

var ret = idevice.idevice_get_device_list(out udids, ref count);

if (ret == iDeviceError.NoDevice)
{

    return;
}

ret.ThrowOnError();

// Get the device serial
foreach (var udid in udids)
{
    LockdownClientHandle lockdownHandle;
    iDeviceHandle deviceHandle;
    LockdownServiceDescriptorHandle ldsHandle;

    idevice.idevice_new(out deviceHandle, udid).ThrowOnError();

    lockdown.lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake(deviceHandle, out 
        lockdownHandle, "Quamotion").ThrowOnError();

    InstallationProxyClientHandle ipc;

    lockdown.lockdownd_start_service(lockdownHandle, 
        "com.apple.mobile.installation_proxy", out ldsHandle);

    ldsHandle.Api.InstallationProxy.instproxy_client_new(deviceHandle, 
        ldsHandle, out ipc);

    ldsHandle.Api.InstallationProxy.instproxy_install(ipc,

    @"C:\configFile.mobileconfig",PlistHandle.Zero,Callback,IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you use, `instproxy_install`, is used to install *applications*. libimobiledevice also ships with [imobileprovision](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/tools/ideviceprovision.c), which is used to install *provisioning profiles*. But you're attempting to install *mobile configuration profiles*, which is something different.

libimobiledevice doesn't provide an API for working with mobile configuration profiles. There are a couple of commercial vendors which can help. The company I work for provides the [imobileconfig](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/download/) command-line utility. I believe some of the folks on the core libimobiledevice team also do consultancy in this area.

One a related note, pushing a mobile configuration profiles will cause the device to skip *most* of the installation wizard, but not all. Again, commercial vendors can help there if needed.

Comment: Will `imobileconfig` allow me to install supervised profiles?